# Convert Chinese characters into XML/HTML-style numerical entities and into Unicode UTF-8?

Tags: python, html, xml, regex, character-encoding

I have a mixture of English words and Chinese characters, and I would like to convert the text into a mixture of English words and the XML/HTML-style numerical entities of the Chinese characters.

For example, the following mixture of English words, numbers and Chinese characters

```
Title: 目录.doc
Level: 1
PageNumber: 1
Begin
Title: 1 C语言概述
Level: 1
PageNumber: 13
BeginTitle: 1.1 Ｃ语言的发展过程
Level: 2
PageNumber: 13
Begin
Title: 1.2 当代最优秀的程序设计语言
```

would be turned into the following, with the Chinese characters replaced by their XML/HTML-style numerical entities:

```
Title: &#30446;&#24405;.doc
Level: 1
PageNumber: 1
Begin
Title: 1 C&#35821;&#35328;&#27010;&#36848;
Level: 1
PageNumber: 13
Begin
Title: 1.1 &#65315;&#35821;&#35328;&#30340;&#21457;&#23637;&#36807;&#31243;
Level: 2
PageNumber: 13
Begin
Title: 1.2 &#24403;&#20195;&#26368;&#20248;&#31168;&#30340;&#31243;&#24207;&#35774;&#35745;&#35821;&#35328;
```

I wonder if I can program this in Python?

Also possible to program for turning the Chinese characters into their Unicode UTF-8 code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If `s` is a unicode string, `s.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')`

In python 2 you can try `s.decode('utf_8').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')`

This works in python 3.

```
s = '''
Title: 目录.doc
Level: 1
PageNumber: 1
Begin
Title: 1 C语言概述
Level: 1
PageNumber: 13
BeginTitle: 1.1 Ｃ语言的发展过程
Level: 2
PageNumber: 13
Begin
Title: 1.2 当代最优秀的程序设计语言
'''

print(s.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace').decode('utf_8'))
```

Alternatively, you can write your own code

```
res = []

for b in s:
    o = ord(b)
    if o > 255:
        res.append('&#{};'.format(o))
    else:
        res.append(b)

res_string = ''.join(res)

print(res_string)
```

Both outputs:

```
Title: &#30446;&#24405;.doc
Level: 1
PageNumber: 1
Begin
Title: 1 C&#35821;&#35328;&#27010;&#36848;
Level: 1
PageNumber: 13
BeginTitle: 1.1 &#65315;&#35821;&#35328;&#30340;&#21457;&#23637;&#36807;&#31243;
Level: 2
PageNumber: 13
Begin
Title: 1.2 &#24403;&#20195;&#26368;&#20248;&#31168;&#30340;&#31243;&#24207;&#35774;&#35745;&#35821;&#35328;
```

You can get the unicode codes using the `ord()` function

```
c = '录'
code = ord(c)
print(code, hex(code))
```

Output:

```
24405 0x5f55
```

Comment: Thanks. +1. what if replacing the Chinese characters into their utf-8 code?